# formData.display() in input field

Tags: javascript, html

Aweber from data display javascript code something look like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">formData.display("name")</script>
<script type="text/javascript">formData.display("email")</script>
<script type="text/javascript">formData.display("phone")</script>
```

Now How can I use this in input filed value like:

```
<form method="post" action="">
<input name="name" type="text" value="<script type="text/javascript">formData.display("name")</script>">
<input name="email" type="text" value="<script type="text/javascript">formData.display("email")</script>">
<input name="phone" type="text" value="<script type="text/javascript">formData.display("phone")</script>">
<input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

Reference: https://help.aweber.com/entries/21696333-How-Do-I-Display-Subscribers-Names-or-Email-Addresses-On-My-Thank-You-Page-

Please help me.

Comment: That is not how JavaScript works.

Comment: Whoa, that tutorial is... interesting.

Answer (score 0):

You can not simple place some code inside a `value` attribute hoping it will work, you need to appropriate JavaScript code to add the `formData` to the `value` attribute of the `input` field. You can do it with something like:

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementsByName('name')[0].value = formData.display("name");
    document.getElementsByName('email')[0].value = formData.display("email");
    document.getElementsByName('phone')[0].value = formData.display("phone");
}
```

Comment: Not work. Its show only 1st value in a white screen.